# Will `mkl_set_num_threads` upper-bound to the number of CPU Threads?

Tags: multithreading, blas, intel-mkl

In OpenBLAS, if you  call `openblas_set_num_threads` asking for a number of threads which is to be higher than the number of CPU threads that you have,
then the actual number of threads it will be set to use is your number of CPU Threads.

This can be seen in the [source code](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/blob/a387a23518b2794b7a9bdebdb7ca35943c50a912/driver/others/blas_server.c#L849-L917)

I am wondering if MKL has the same behavior?
The [docs](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-mkl-set-num-threads) do not explicitly mention it.
but they do say:

> The number specified is a hint, and Intel® MKL may actually use a smaller number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MKL behavior is different and as matter of fact you can have more threads than there are cores.

The reason @Kristoffer doesn't see this in his answer, is because the dynamic adjustment is [enabled per default](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-threading-control):

> By default, Intel® MKL can adjust the specified number of threads
>   dynamically. [...] If dynamic adjustment of the number of threads
>   is disabled, Intel® MKL attempts to use the specified number of
>   threads in internal parallel regions (for more information, see
>   theIntel® MKL Developer Guide). Use the mkl_set_dynamic function to
>   control dynamic adjustment of the number of threads.

So if we use `mkl_set_dynamic(0)` to switch the dynamic adjustment off, we will see the following:

```
>>> set_max_threads(44)
>>> get_max_threads()  
6
>>> mkl_set_dynamic(0)
>>> get_max_threads()
44
```

So we see, that without dynamic adjustment MKL could use 44 threads. Whether this is really the case is another question, the help to [`mkl_get_dynamic`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-mkl-get-dynamic) explains (even if the information seems to be a little bit outdated to me as `get_max_threads` already is taken into consideration in `get_max_threads`):

> Suppose that the `mkl_get_max_threads` function returns the number of threads
>   equal to N. [...] If dynamic
>   adjustment is disabled, Intel ® MKL requests exactly N threads for
>   internal parallel regions ([...]). However, the
>   OpenMP* run-time library may be configured to supply **fewer threads**
>   than Intel ® MKL requests, depending on the OpenMP* setting of dynamic
>   adjustment.

OpenMP's method is given in Algorithm 2.1 [OpenMP-5.0 specification](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu35.html#x55-880002.6.1) (which I don't pretend to understand).

On my machine the important values are `omp_get_thread_limit()=2147483647` and  `omp_get_dynamic()=0`, and so disabling `MKL_DYNAMIC` and setting maximal thread-number higher I really can see descrease of performance due to more overhead.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to cap at the number of cores (not the number of threads). The code below ran on a 6-Core Intel Core i7:

```
julia> using MKL_jll

julia> get_max_threads() = ccall((:mkl_get_max_threads, libmkl_rt), Int32, ());

julia> set_max_threads(n) = ccall((:mkl_set_num_threads, libmkl_rt), Cvoid, (Ptr{Int32},), Ref(Int32(n)));

julia> get_max_threads()
6

julia> set_max_threads(4)

julia> get_max_threads()
4

julia> set_max_threads(8)

julia> get_max_threads() # maxed out at 6
6

julia> set_max_threads(24)

julia> get_max_threads() # maxed out at 6
6

julia> set_max_threads(1)

julia> get_max_threads()
1
```